# Python: How to handle Received headers in SMTP relay?

Tags: python, email

I have an application that sends buggy SMTP messages. The vendor has been promising for years to fix it, but I've given up hope and am writing an SMTP relay.

According to the standards, each time a server receives an SMTP message, it is supposed to add a new Received: line at the beginning of the header block.  I don't see an easy way to do this. When an email arrives, I use `email.message_from_string()` to parse everything. `message.add_header` will append another Received header, but not insert one at the beginning. The best solution I can see is to use `msg.get_all('Received')` to extract all of the headers, then `del msg['Received']` to get rid of them all, and finally add mine and all the others back in. This doesn't seem very elegant.

Is there a better way that I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered prepending  new `Received:` to message-string itself?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wound up doing. I'm thinking about submitting a bug report.